# Kali Linux installation - Kernel panic

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kernel-panic

I'm trying to install Kali Linux (2017.3 32-bit) on my VirtualBox (5.2.2) but when I select 'Install' from the menu, I get an error saying Kernel panic and bad EIP value. After that nothing happens. Please see the attached photo.
[image: Kali Linux Kernel panic]

Other specs:

- VM version: Linux 2.6 / 3.x / 4.x (32-bit)
- PAE/NX enabled
- 1024 MB RAM

I have the VM on a Win10 machine. The ISO checksum matches for my download.  have tried installation with Debian (32bit) as well and it worked just fine.

Comment: Debian 32bit. My VM only allows 32bit.

Comment: From a pragmatic perspective, would Debian satisfy your needs?

Comment: Well, not really, because I want to try Kali Linux and its capabilities specifically.

Comment: Yes, the checksums match

Comment: If you are new to kali, use dual boot. Some amount of experience is required to configure kali with Virtual Machines.

Comment: @defalt this isn't a Kali configuration issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running a 64bit host OS (Windows 7). But you say that you can run only 32bit guests. The reason for this is that you need to enable virtualisation settings in the BIOS.